# Insert into column when number missing

Tags: excel

Say I have a column in Excel like this:

```
15
14
13
10
9
6
1
```

And I need to insert a value where when a number is skipped, a new cell is inserted into it's place, it doesn't have to be a number it could just be "FALSE". But it needs to do this WITHOUT adding an entire row, just that cell and value. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean without adding a new row? Would that be necessary to have a place to put the number?

Comment: Is it that you would like to have 12 and 11 show up between the 13 and 10? Would not two rows have to be inserted between them? Or do you want to move the entire column of numbers down to accommodate?

Comment: I would need to move the whole column of numbers down, preserving the next column

Comment: or, I could bring that column into a separate spreadsheet and do it there and add as many rows as needed, but the values added would have to be values like "FALSE", and it would have to work even with multiple gaps in numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm playing now but if you loop and use the below it'll work:

```vb
Cells(1,1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

With VBA use the following code. **Right click** on the sheet tab and click **view code**, paste this in and run it:

```vb
Sub add_rows(ByVal myCol As String)
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim l As Long, i As Long, myCol As String
        myCol = "E" '<~~ alter this for your column
        l = .Columns(myCol).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row '<~~ get last row in column
        i = 1

        Do While i <= l

            If i > 1 Then '<~~ not first row?
                Dim c1, c2 'get cell values
                c1 = .Cells(i - 1, myCol).Value
                c2 = .Cells(i, myCol).Value

                If c1 - 1 > c2 Then
                        'shift cells down by the numbers missing
                        .Cells(i, myCol).Resize(c1 - c2 - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        'set to false
                        .Cells(i, myCol).Resize(c1 - c2 - 1) = False

                        'increase variable by number of inserted rows
                        l = l + c1 - c2 - 1 
                        i = i + c1 - c2 - 1
                End If
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that VB? Not sure how to use that

Comment: Yes, this is vba. Hopefully I've explained enough. :)